# SearchEverything equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: search

On Windows I can use [SearchEverything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to quickly and easily find any file or folder on my PC. What are equivalent programs/commands for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the find command inside of the directory that you wish to search in:

```
find -iname *.exe
```

The -iname parameter tells the program to search for filename using case insensitivity. For more information about this command you can use the following which will show the manual page for find:

```
man find
```

The previous is what I use but there is also a nice article [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles) that shows many more ways to find files including graphical ways.

Comment: So if I go into my root directory and do 'find something' it'll search the whole computer for 'something'

Comment: Not exactly. You need to use "-iname" to search for files by name - or just "-name" if you are doing a case sensitive search . And it will find only the files with the exact name you enter if you don't use a wildcard (*). In your root directory I would probably use "sudo find" in order to not see a bunch of Permission Denied errors.